# Silverlight 2 Zindex Issue on ASP.NET Page IE6

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-6, silverlight-2.0, z-index

I Have a Silverlight Menu on a ASP.NET page, 
on this page bellow the menu there's a Html Table 
and bellow the table there's a dropdownlist.

The silverlight DIV is position: absolute; z-index: 999;
The silverlight App is designed with zindex in its elements, is windowless, and background transparent.

This Works fine on Firefox however in IE6 (requirement) it doesn't work, the silverlight gets bellow the html table and dropdownlist

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Gabriel

Comment: Is that working or not working ???

Comment: then its working on both rite..

Comment: Not working (on IE6 it appears bellow the table and dropdown):
Sorry I just saw I wrote it worked on the question, changed for the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only spent a small amount of time reading up on this particular problem, but it seems that this is a problem with most z-index settings with IE6.

> It appears that in Internet Explorer
>   (windows) positioned elements do
>   generate a new stacking context,
>   starting with a z-index value of 0 [quote](http://www.last-child.com/conflicting-z-index-in-ie6/)

I found an [article](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) that addresses this issue by setting the parent div's z-indexes as well. However, you mention that the Silverlight div has a z-index specified, but no code, so I can only guess that what you have done might be the same as in the article.

There is another [article](http://www.hedgerwow.com/360/bugs/css-select-free.html) that makes use of iFrames, that you might want to look at as well.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry none of the solutions worked, aparently if I use the second one purely the div gets on top of the controls I want, but when I mix with my silverlight control things get messed up

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to solve the problem with a nasty javascript.

The think is the IFrame solved most of the problem, another part I had to remove any position: relative i had used, and there was still the ASP.NET DropDownList's that got on front of my silverilght Menu, I didn't have the time to solve this on a 'correct' way (if I can even say this). I had to use javascript to hide the DropDownList's and when the user hover out of the menu I'll show the dropdownlist's again.

[this link with a working example helped me a lot.](http://www.hedgerwow.com/360/bugs/css-select-free.html)

Thanks for the help everyone that helped.